# Replace mantaining case in Regular Expressions

Tags: regex, replace

Using editor regular expression search and replace, I need to subsitute "Bob" with "James" and "bob" with "james" at once, and I must avoid to replace partial matches like "ob" with "james" or "James".
Is it possible?
Thanks.

P.S. I'm using the Notepad++ editor and the Visual Studio IDE, but any suggestions for other editors/IDE are welcome.

Comment: Thanks, @Wiktor. I tried to use "(b)?(B)?ob" in find, and "(?1james:James)" in replace, and I checked the match case, but it replace also "ob" with "James". Any suggestion?

Comment: Use `(bob)|(Bob)`